# Brownian Motions probability of stopping time

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

> Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a stochastic process with $X_t=(B^{(1)}_t+1, B^{(2)}_t,B^{(3)}_t, ..., B^{(n)}_t )$ with $B^{(i)}_t$ independent Brownian motions, $n\geq3$. Let $\tau_m := \inf \{ t \geq 0 : ||X||_2 = m\}$. Determine $P(\tau_r > \tau_R) , 0 < r < 1 < R < \infty$.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to start.. Thanks for any help how to determine this probability!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac12\Delta$ is the generator of Brownian Motion, which means that for any function $u$ satisfying $\Delta u=0$, the process $M_t:=u(B_t)$ is a martingale. Think about why this is true.

Now consider the PDE $$\begin{align*}-\frac12 \Delta u&=0 , \text{  on } \{r<|x|<R\}\\ u(x)&=0, \text{ for } |x|=r \\ u(x)&=1, \text{for }|x|=R \end{align*}$$ then the solution of the PDE given above is equal to $$u(x)=\mathbb P\big[\tau_R<\tau_r\big| B_0=x\big]$$
again, try to prove this (Hint: Optional Sampling Theorem).

Hence, solving this PDE and setting $x=e_1$ gives the desired solution.

Alternatively you could set up the SDE for $\Vert X\Vert$,i.e. find coefficients $b(x),\sigma(x)$ such that $$d\Vert X_t\Vert=b(\Vert X\Vert)dt+\sigma(\Vert X\Vert)dB_t,$$ compute it's generator $L$ based on the coefficients $b,\sigma$; then solve the associated PDE $Lu=0$ with $u(r)=0,u(R)=1$ (which will then be $1$-dimensional!) and obtain the same solution. This approach is perhaps easier.

Comment: Thank you for your help! How do I set up the SDE for $||X||$? I was thinking of applying Ito onto $f(X_t)=||X_t||$: $$d||X_t||=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f(X_t)}{\partial X^i}dX_t^i+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{\partial f(X_t)}{\partial X^i\partial X^j}d[X_t^i,X_t^j]$$ How do I determine this? It is $||X||_2=\sqrt{(B^{(1)}_t+1)^2+ (B^{(2)}_t)^2+(B^{(3)}_t)^2+ ...+ (B^{(n)}_t)^2}$

Comment: I see you set up a Dirichlet problem? The only proposition I have found is: Let $u$ be a solution of $$\begin{cases}Lu=0 & \Omega \\ u=f &\partial\Omega\end{cases}$$ and let $\tau:=\inf\{t\geq0:X_t\notin\Omega\}$. Then $P_x(X_t\in E)=\int_Em(x,y)\sigma(dy))$ for $E\subset\partial\Omega$ with the same $\sigma$ as you mentioned above. I don't know if it's helpful in this case.

Comment: @Uhmm You can consider $X=(B_t^{(1)},\dots,B_t^{(n)})$, dropping the $1$. This doesn't change the SDE, only the initial value.

Comment: @Uhmm There is a very simple solution to this specific Dirichlet problem. Hint: $u$ must be radially symmetric, i.e. $u(x)$ only depends on $|x|$.

Comment: Okay, I determined $d||X_t||=\frac{\langle B^{(i)}_t, dB^{(i)}_t\rangle}{||X_t||}+\frac{n-1}{2||X_t||}dt$, wouldn't this be some kind of Bessel process? I still don't know how to determine $\mathbb{P}(\tau_r>\tau_R)$ tbh

Comment: @Uhmm I don't think that SDE is correct. You miscalculated the second derivative of $|\cdot|^2$.

Comment: I cannot see any mistake: $\left(\frac{B_t^{(i)}}{||X_t||}\right)'=\frac{||X_t||-\frac{(B_t^{(i)})^2}{||X_t||}}{||X||^2}=\frac{1}{||X_t||}-\frac{(B_t^{(i)})^2}{||X_t||^3}$, taking the sum yields $\frac{n-1}{||X_t||}$